# How should I create a custom flowdocument control that has its own visual presentation?

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

How would I make a control that allows me to keep repeating certain FlowDocument elements.

I want to be able to have Xaml that looks like this:

```
<MyCustomControl>
    <Paragraph>Paragraph 1</Paragraph>
</MyCustomControl>
```

But have it render as if it were something like this:

```
<Section>
    <Paragraph>This is Header Text</Paragraph>
    <Section> <!-- this is user area -->
        <Paragraph>Paragraph 1</Paragraph>
    </Section>
    <Paragraph>This is Footer Text</Paragraph>
</Section>
```

---

I tried descending from Section, and putting this bonus content in an attribute

(Bad and ugly code ahead)

```
<MyCustomControl StuffOnInside="&ltParagraph&gtParagraph 1&lt/Paragraph&gt" />
```

but then when it was serialized, it serialized the `StuffOnInside` twice, creating duplicate data, and a big mess when it came to other things

```
<MyCustomControl StuffOnInside="&ltParagraph&gtParagraph 1&lt/Paragraph&gt">
    <Paragraph>This is Header Text</Paragraph>
    <Section> <!-- this is user area -->
        <Paragraph>Paragraph 1</Paragraph>
    </Section>
    <Paragraph>This is Footer Text</Paragraph>
</MyCustomControl>
```